# sed regex pre-append not working with a different input

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following `sed` replace, which works correctly

```
$ echo "1.1.1.1\n2.2.2.2" | sed "s/^/allow /g; s/$/;/g"
allow 1.1.1.1;
allow 2.2.2.2;
```

However, when I run the same regex against a list of IPs, it shows incorrectly

```
$ wget -q https://api.bunny.net/system/edgeserverlist/plain -O - | sed "s/^/allow /g; s/$/;/g"
;llow 84.17.46.49
;llow 185.93.1.242
;llow 185.152.67.139
...
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You probably wanted to say that `echo -e "1.1.1.1\n2.2.2.2" | sed "s/^/allow /g; s/$/;/g"` works correctly. Without `-e`, it does not.

Comment: The problem is on wget version, not on the echo

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: I expect `allow 84.17.46.49;` not `;llow 84.17.46.49`

Comment: `sed "s/\r$//g; s/^/allow /g; s/$/;/g" test.txt`. Remove all CRs at the end of lines.

Comment: This worked, you can awnser the question

Comment: Why are you using double quotes instead of single around your script - are you running this on Windows?

Comment: I do not know, is the standard on Unix single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all carriage returns at the end of lines before running your sed commands:

```bash
sed "s/\r$//g; s/^/allow /g; s/$/;/g"
```

This will output a list of `allow` + IPs:

```
allow 89.187.185.87;
allow 212.102.50.49;
allow 84.17.46.50;
allow 89.187.173.70;
allow 89.187.185.163;
allow 84.17.37.209;
allow 89.187.185.162;
allow 89.187.188.223;
```

etc.